# How do I get my Hadoop python mapper to work?

Tags: python, hadoop

I want to try write python mapper functions for Hadoop MapReduce (as a complete beginner).  I've tried the code below and although it runs it returns "terminated- steps completed with errors".  I used the default aggregate reducer function.

```
import sys

keywords = ["bear", "bears"]
for line in sys.stin:
    words = line.split()
    for key in keywords:
        if key in words[1:]:
            ans = words[words.index(key)-1] 
            print("%s\t%d" % (ans, 1))
```

(Thanks in advance)

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in sys.stin:
```

should be

```
for line in sys.stdin:
```

In general, you should test your script before running it on hadoop map-reduce with:

```
cat test_file.txt | python your_mapper.py | sort | python your_reducer.py
```

Then you would have seen the AttributeError.

Comment: Thanks (swore I'd never post here with a typo!) , I still can't get it to work though.  I suspect I just don't know enough about using hadoop map-reduce.  I was running it by creating a cluster as I would for the standard wordcount but by substituting my own mapper, but perhaps I need to learn more about the whole thing.

Comment: Did you try the command line test?  Did that work?  If so, could you post your call to hadoop map-reduce?

Comment: I've no idea how to do that :( I've been using EMR on Amazon with no instruction except how to run a word count...

Comment: Basically, I'm asking if your script works properly on your local machine.  Are you using windows or a unix based system?

Comment: Sorry, yes, and I've tried it with the same test text file as I'm using on Hadoop and it works perfectly